# Change BOOLEAN to LOGICAL in generated sql script by FDTable

Tags: delphi, firedac, dbase

I have a FDTable with TBooleanField.
The database is dBase IV.

I want to create the table with:

```
<TFDTable>.CreateTable(False, [tpTable]);
```

This works if I don't have a TBooleanField in the table.

In the SQL script that generated on CreateTable the TBooleanField is of type BOOLEAN. Is there something in property of FDConnection or FDTable that change the BOOLEAN to LOGICAL.

SQL Script:

```
CREATE TABLE ACT_01 (
  ISDOC BOOLEAN,  
  DOCTYPE VARCHAR(1))
```

Must change in:

```
CREATE TABLE ACT_01 (
  ISDOC LOGICAL,  
  DOCTYPE VARCHAR(1))
```

Ok, I can execute the sql myself without the createtable but I want to know if it is possible to change the BOOLEAN to LOGICAL from the methode  TFDTable.CreateTable

FDConnection:

```
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=ODBC');
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('ODBCDriver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)}');
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('Database=C:\Projects\Test Projects\DBase table\Data');
```

Comment: If you're using the proper driver, it should take care of those sorts of detail for you. The Advantage driver, for instance, automatically maps TBooleanField to a logical field and does all value conversions transparently.

Comment: @KenWhite: Do you mean that I must use the Advantage driver?

Comment: No, I mean that the driver should take care of those sorts of conversions for you automatically *if you're using an appropriate driver*, which is what I said in my first sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: @Ken, Advantage is an exception. The rest is hardcoded at this time, though `SQLGetTypeInfo` could be helpful here (see how `IFDPhysCommandGenerator.GetColumnType` is implemented).

Answer (score 0):

FireDAC uses hardcoded data types for generating **CREATE** command for all *unsupported* ODBC drivers (the ODBC command generator's **GetColumnType** method doesn't query driver for DBMS data type names).

What's more, FireDAC [**does not recognize**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Intf.TFDDataType) any **ftLogical** data type, so you cannot create a custom data type mapping even though that's just what you were supposed to do here.

So, you're out of luck at this time.